# Avoid many if conditions

Tags: ios, swift

i have 6 strings (text,year,age,....) i want to filter array based on them ... i want to check before if the string is empty or not .. if not empty then added to the if condition as an && .. but how to do something like this without the need to write many if conditions on each string with each other string ?

i want to avoid doing something like this:

```
if self.searchtext != "" && self.qualification != ""{

}else if self.searchtext != "" && self.qualification != "" && self.gender != ""{

}else if self.searchtext != "" && self.qualification != "" && self.gender != "" && self.year != ""{

}else if self.searchtext != "" && self.qualification != "" && self.gender != "" && self.year != "" && self.major != ""{

}
....
```

How to do this?

```
if self.searchtext != ""{
                            if user.name.contains(find: self.searchtext) || user.mobile.contains(find: self.searchtext) || user.email.contains(find: self.searchtext){
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.phones.append(user.mobile)
                                    self.names.append(user.name)
                                }
                            }
                        }else if self.qualification != ""{
                            if user.qualification.contains(find: self.qualification){
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.phones.append(user.mobile)
                                    self.names.append(user.name)
                                }
                            }
                        }else if self.gender != ""{
                            if user.gender.contains(find: self.gender){
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.phones.append(user.mobile)
                                    self.names.append(user.name)
                                }
                            }
                        }else if self.year != ""{
                            if user.graduateYear.contains(find: self.year){
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.phones.append(user.mobile)
                                    self.names.append(user.name)
                                }
                            }
                        }else if self.major != ""{
                            if user.specialization.contains(find: self.major){
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.phones.append(user.mobile)
                                    self.names.append(user.name)
                                }
                            }
                        }else if self.city != ""{
                            if user.city.contains(find: self.city){
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.phones.append(user.mobile)
                                    self.names.append(user.name)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

This is what i have working .. but this works as an OR when i want it to be like AND for all none empty strings

Comment: Are you sure you want the conditions in that order? Do you not want to first check `if self.searchtext != "" && self.qualification != "" && self.gender != "" && self.year != "" && self.major != ""` before you **ONLY** check their qualification?

Comment: Please, write working code. Neither of the `else if` branch can happen.

Comment: @Sulthan just updated it ..

Comment: You can use `String.isEmpty` instead of comparing to an empty string

Answer (score 4):

Here's a paragraph copied from [LinkedIn's style guide](https://github.com/linkedin/swift-style-guide#311-using-guard-statements)

> Using guard Statements
>
> 3.11.1 In general, we prefer to use an "early return" strategy where applicable as opposed to nesting code in if statements. Using guard statements for this use-case is often helpful and can improve the readability of the code.

```
// PREFERRED
func eatDoughnut(at index: Int) {
    guard index >= 0 && index < doughnuts.count else {
        // return early because the index is out of bounds
        return
    }

    let doughnut = doughnuts[index]
    eat(doughnut)
}

// NOT PREFERRED
func eatDoughnut(at index: Int) {
    if index >= 0 && index < doughnuts.count {
        let doughnut = doughnuts[index]
        eat(doughnut)
    }
}
```

It's what I personally do, and it's a good convention to avoid nested if's.

In your case, you can do a couple of things. First and foremost, use `.isEmpty` instead of comparing the string to an empty string (`""`). If your only intent is to check if all your strings are empty, you can accomplish that like this:

```
    let strings = [searchtext, qualification, ...]
    guard strings.filter({ $0.isEmpty }).count == 0 else {
        return
    }

    // Code that only works if all fields have values
```

Comment: guard strings.filter({ $0.isEmpty }).count == 0 else {
        return
    } will go inside only if all of the string is not empty?

Comment: i want to do something with all of the none empty strings.. i don't need them all to be not empty

Comment: i will take those who are not empty and do some && with them

Answer (score 3):

We can certainly simplify things a lot.

I would start by wrapping search criteria into an object:

```
struct UserSearchCriteria {
   var searchText = ""
   var gender = ""
   var qualification = ""
   ...

   init() {}
}
```

Then you can use one variable instead of your X variables:

```
var searchCriteria = UserSearchCriteria()
```

then you can add a simple matching method:

```
extension UserSearchCriteria {
   func matchesUser(_ user: User) -> Bool {
      if !searchText.isEmpty && [user.name, user.mobile, user.email].contains(where: { $0.contains(find: searchText) }) { 
         return true
      }

      if !qualification.isEmpty && user.qualification.contains(find: qualification) {
         return true
      }

      ...

      return false
   }
}
```

Then your big condition is reduced to:

```
if self.searchCriteria.matches(user) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.phones.append(user.mobile)
      self.names.append(user.name)
   }
}
```

You cannot really avoid the conditions, but you can simplify them and organize them better, without duplicating code.

It seems you want to match all search conditions then I would change the matching method to:

```
func matchesUser(_ user: User) -> Bool {
      if !searchText.isEmpty && ![user.name, user.mobile, user.email].contains(where: { $0.contains(find: searchText) }) { 
         return false
      }

      if !qualification.isEmpty && !user.qualification.contains(find: qualification) {
         return false
      }

      ...

      return true
   }
```

(note the double negation - `contains` condition negated and returning `false`).

Comment: okay... but this will work the same as || (OR) right? for example if i have 2 string s not empty .. this will append both of the separately .. i mean not append user when string1 && string2 appears in user .. right?

Comment: @Lama I see, you only have specified that in a comment. Let me update.

Comment: what i mean is that i want to append the user when all of the none empty string is existing in him ..

Comment: @Lama And search string is empty? You have to *understand* that first and then update it for you exact use case. Don't just blindly copy-paste, please. Updated again.

Comment: i don't get how does it work actually .. for example when i filter based on gender .. it will return all genders not only the gender i selected ...

Comment: @Lama Then you are not writing your conditions correctly.

Comment: why? i did the exact same as what you posted?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Guard statement](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html) to Early exit a scope .

> A guard statement is used to transfer program control out of a scope
> if one or more conditions aren’t met.

This will pass only if all fields are not empty.

```
guard self.searchtext != "", self.qualification != "", self.gender != "", self.year != "", self.major != "" else { return }
```

---

Update:

```
guard let searchText = self.searchtext, !searchText.isEmpty else { return }
// do something with `searchText`. Here the above conditions will be true.
```

OR you can use `if-let`

```
if let searchText = self.searchtext, !searchText.isEmpty {
    // do with `searchText`(non-optional). 
} else {
    // conditions failed.
}
```

---

If you are trying to filter your array, you can simply use `array.filter`

```
let filteredUsers = usersArray.filter {
       let shouldIAddThisElement = $0.name.contains(searchText) // Do your logic here
       return shouldIAddThisElement
}
```

Comment: sorry this is new to me .. and then how i continue inside? i want to do something like this user.qualification.contains(find: self.qualification) for each string .. can u please tell me how to continue?

Comment: If you are trying to filter your array, you can simply use array.filter. `let filteredUsers = usersArray.filter { $0.name!.contains(searchtext) || $0.mobile!.contains(searchtext) || $0.email!.contains(searchtext) }
`

Comment: ok this is great .. but how to do the same and check if searchtext, age ,.. not empty before?

Comment: not all of them should be not empty .. all of them are optional .. so i don't know which will be not empty

Comment: i don't think your updated answer will work with such senario right?

Comment: Now you have idea about how to solve your problem. You may use `.filter`, `guard-let` or `if-let` as you need. Put these options & your logic together. :-] . It will work.

Comment: Which of them are optional? And what's you search criteria? Is there any priorities?

Comment: How the data should filtered?

Comment: i filter it based on the 6 strings: searchtext, age, gender, qualification, city and major .. any of these strings if they are not empty i will take the users in which they have the same age && gender && .... (all of the none empty strings)

Comment: answer updated. Hope this is your actual requirement.

Comment: got this error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'

Answer (score 0):

Swift includes `guard` statement. The lines after the `guard` statement will only be executed if the guard condition is true. Like an `if/else` statement, the `else` clause runs if the condition is false.

```
guard condition else {
  // false: execute some code
}

// true: execute some code
```

For your case:

```
guard self.searchtext && self.qualification && self.gender && self.year && self.major else { return }
// execute some code
```

The `return` statement will exit the function or method.

More information can be found in the documentation on "Early Exit" Section:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html